# Installing a 64bit OS on the Raspberry Pi 3 that supports latest MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, operating-system, raspberry-pi, 64-bit

I have a Raspberry Pi 3. It runs a 64bit processor. I need the latest features of MongoDB, but it requires a 64bit OS to run the 64bit program. I can not find a 64bit OS that runs on the Raspberry Pi 3 and supports the latest version of MongoDB.

How do I install the latest version of MongoDB on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: I haven't tried the Pi 3, but modern MongoDB releases for the Pi can unofficially be found [here](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve this by installing openSUSE 64bit for the Raspberry Pi 3
https://en.opensuse.org/HCL:Raspberry_Pi3

Once installed, you can download aarch64 pre-compiled binaries of MongoDB v3.4 for the Raspberry Pi 3 from mongo-pi.com
https://www.mongo-pi.com/resources